# Pure Python way of calculating trig functions?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a small Python script that I want to convert into a single file executable using `pyinstaller`.

The script essentially takes an input file, manipulates it and writes an output file.

However, I need to calculate the tangent function in the script, and when I do this using either `numpy.tan()` or `math.tan()`, the final executable ends up being ridiculously huge because `pyinstaller` bundles either the whole numpy or math modules in the executable.

Thus, my question is, is there a pure python method to calculate trig functions?

My first though was that it must be possible to define sin, cos and tan purely mathematically, but I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken the math module is already part of python

Comment: I don't see how you'd bundle Python *without* the `math` module. Are you *sure* that usage of `math.tan` has an effect on the executable size? (I'm very skeptical.)

Comment: Have you tried `from math import tan` instead of just `import math` at the top of your source file? (You'd then call it using `tan()` instead of `math.tan()`.

Comment: @RobH: That won't work: either form of the `import` statement loads the entire module. They differ solely in which names they make available in the module dictionary.

Comment: So the code is really small, about 50 lines, and the executable is 5.9MB, which seems unnecessarily large for a very small code. If I use numpy.math, the file is about 350MB! Initially I though that pyinstaller compiles the python script into C or something, which I expect that the executable should be very small. But if it actually bundles a part of Python with it, then I suppose 5MB isn't too bad.

Comment: @pp_ Oops. You're right. Been away from Python for too long. Just edited the comment to fix that blunder.

Comment: Don't use `numpy.math`; just import directly from `math`.

Comment: you can also find [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes) to _sin_ and _cos_ in decimal module

Comment: @Copperfield: The `decimal` module imports `math`, so that wouldn't avoid the use of the `math` module. But the entire premise of this question is bogus anyway: importing from `math` (*not* `numpy.math`) is not going to have an effect on the size of the generated executable.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, "importing from math (not numpy.math) " has absolutely nothing to do with my question? So I think its a little uncalled for calling it bogus.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: you don't need to import decimal or math or anything else to use those recipes, just use them as they are presented in the documentation and discard the `getcontext().prec` part and add `x = x % (2 * 3.141592653589793)` at the start with or without some check in magnitud of x and they work perfectly fine

Comment: @Jonny: You say "when I do this using either numpy.tan() or math.tan(), the final executable ends up being ridiculously huge". That's simply not true: it may be true for `numpy,` but the `math` module is a part of Python anyway, so using `math.tan` is not going to lead to an increase in executable size. There's simply no need to use Taylor series or anything else: just use `math.tan`.

Comment: @Copperfield: Ah, I misunderstood. Yes, indeed those recipes would give you the necessary Taylor series. But it's still rather pointless, given that there's no good reason not to just use the `math` module. (There's also no need for Taylor series either, when a 2-line use of `e**(1j*angle)` gives you the `sin` and `cos` directly with no imports at all.)

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I discovered myself after I implemented the tailor series. I'm a bit disappointed in pyinstaller, but I read now that it actually bundles the python interpreter with the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/trig.cfm

the taylor series expansion is a usual numerical method to solve to arbitary precision.

By the way, you should take care of the cyclic property of the trig functions as the error is proportional to the input (well to some power of it), if you do not expect mostly well behaved usage.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I needed. Except, the executable stays exactly the same size, so I assume pyinstaller bundles many unnecessary things with the executable in any way.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to express trigonometric functions with complex numbers: [Eulers formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry)

As this would however require you to perform complex math, and you would have to import *cmath*, you would need to implement complex math on your own if you want to go this way.

Otherwise, a simple approximation can be acquired by evaluating a [taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions). Again, as *import math* is not an option, this requires you to implement some pretty fundamental stuff like powers and factorials on your own.

Comment: No need to import the `cmath` module: just do `e**(theta*1j)`.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. This is exactly what I needed but Chris's answer was 1 min before yours (-: However the executable stays the same size if I do it using a taylor series in any way.